# Django user authentication: not redirecting after login

Tags: django, authentication

My website has a front page that has a link to a forum. Access to the forum requires that the user be logged in. I have therefore given the view show_forum the decorator: @login_required. When the user clicks the forum link, they are correctly redirected to the login page. Once the user has logged in they are, however, taken back to the front page, not to the forum page. If the user now (being logged in) clicks the forum link then he is taken directly to the forum page.

Via Firebug, I can see that the url is getting the correct 'next' parameter. Any hints or things that I should look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My most common issue with the `login_required` decorator is that I forget to redirect to the `next` parameter while having a custom login view in place. In other words, the page gets built up in segments, and after a while the login feature gets added. By default, this view redirects to a default index page (what you probably equals to your "front page").

What this boils down to is: do you have something like the following in your `/accounts/login/` view?

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next', settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL))
```

Comment: Thanks, this totally helped me, although it wasn't exactly my issue. I forgot that I had created a custom login template. Here I had forgotten to include <input type="hidden" name="next"  value="{{ next }}" />